# How angular 4 works with SASS (BEM)?

Tags: angular, sass, bem

It works, but angular includes "_grid.scss" with every executable component and inserts it in head. :(
How does include my sass-libs in project properly?

header.component.scss

```
@import '../../scss/partials/_variables.scss';
@import '../../scss/partials/_grid.scss';

.main-header{
    width: 100%;
    background: $black;
    color: $white;
    min-height: 3rem;
    &__wrapper{
        @extend .container;
        @extend .flex-grid;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Part of angular-cli.json:

```
  "styles": [
    "styles.scss"
  ],
  "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
    "includePaths": [
      "src/scss"
    ]
```

styles.scss

```
@import "scss/partials/_normalize.scss";
```

Comment: If you're using angular-cli you can add your style main.scss file with partial' imports to it and then globally add your main.scss file to `.angular-cli.json` config. It will works with BEM and you don't have to import anything to components at all :)

Comment: I have tried it. But, when i import all partials in common scss file @extend doesn't work in header.components .